# fill numpy array with specific values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 5x5 array with zeros.
import numpy as np

```
x = np.zeros((5,5)):

[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I want to fill 1's at certain positions:

```
input=[(2,2),(1,1),(3,4)] :
     [[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
     [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

how do I do that given input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use itemset

`[x.itemset(t, 1) for t in input]`

in tuple you set the locacation and last argument is the value to set

Answer (score 0):

```
x = np.zeros((5,5))
for pair in input:
    x[pair[0]][pair[1]]=1
```

code is self explanatory.